# Search data from mysql database like elastic search

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch data from whole `mysql` database not in single table.
It works when I try to search using `LIKE` query but it works only with specific key.

I try to search who is admin so it will return all the data related (`admin name` or `email`) from `mysql` table

I try this code :

```
$this->db->select()
->like('username', 'admin')
->like('email','admin@gmail.com')
->get('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you:**

Use `or_like`  in your  query and select clause should be like `$this->db->select('*')`

```
$username = 'your-username';
$email = 'your-email';
$results = $this->db->select('*')
       ->like('username', $username)
       ->or_like('email',$email)
       ->get('users')->result();
print_r($results);
```

If u want to get result  with specific `username` and `email` u can also use `where` clause like this :

```
$username = 'your-username';
$email = 'your-email';
$results = $this->db->select('*')
            ->where('username', $username)
            ->or_where('email',$email)
            ->get('users')->result();
print_r($results);
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data